# Setting the class on a CollectionView item based on the value of the item

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to set the class of my itemViewClass view based on an attribute of the value's content.

The code below produces:

```
<span id="ember326" class="ember-view spanValue">
<h5>
<script id="metamorph-32-start" type="text/x-placeholder">
Select
<script id="metamorph-32-end" type="text/x-placeholder">
</h5>
</span>
```

class is set to 'spanValue' instead of the value from the content.

Any ideas?

thanks.

```
listHeaderView: Ember.CollectionView.create({
classNames: ['jobs-list-header', 'row'],
content: [
    Ember.Object.create({
        span: 'span1',
        label: 'Select'
    }),
    Ember.Object.create({
        span: 'span1',
        label: 'Status'
    }),
    Ember.Object.create({
        span: 'span1',
        label: 'Tax Year'
    }),
    Ember.Object.create({
        span: 'span3',
        label: 'Municipality'
    }),
    Ember.Object.create({
        span: 'span3',
        label: 'School District'
    }),
    Ember.Object.create({
        span: 'span1',
        label: 'Received'
    })
],
itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'span',
    classNames: ['spanValue'],
    spanValue: function() {
        return this.get('content').span
    }.property(),
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<h5>{{content.label}}</h5>')
})
```

}),

Answer (score 3):

there's a couple of things here.

Firstly `return this.get('content').span` should probably use `return this.getPath('content.span')` or similar.

However, your main problem lies in the fact you should be using `classNameBindings`, not `classNames` when defining your itemViewClass.

Hope that helps

Comment: classNameBindings can use deep paths, too, so you can bind to 'content.span' instead of needing to create a local property for it.